# Is it possible to make so the wind starts from some particular plane and doesn't affect anything behind that plane?

Tags: force-fields

I have a single image of a coat that I am trying to animate. Wind and cloth effects are what I need but the problem is I want to set 4 different sources of wind for different directions and make it so the wind blows from its own plane and doesn't affect anything behind the plane

Comment: ok, found it nvm. In physics properties there is a Z direction option

Comment: Okay, I was just about to write an answer ;)

Comment: @Jurby Please add this answer to your own question so it will not remain in the unanswered list, and later researchers can find it.

Comment: @TheLabCat sure

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In case somebody stumbles upon the same problem. *Click the wind object -> then Physics Property tab --> in Falloff section choose Z Direction to +Z*. The wind now blows strictly "from" the wind emitter in direction of the normal, not from behind.[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)